# Firebird and SQL Server delete highest rows in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird

I need to delete the 3rd and greater records, sorted by product, type and display order, from the following tables:

`Stockist` table:

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS
(
  STOCKISTID     NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRODUCTID  NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
  DISPLAYORDER   NUMERIC(10,0),
  CUSTOMERID     NUMERIC(10,0),
CONSTRAINT PK_INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS PRIMARY KEY (STOCKISTID)
);
```

`STOCKISTID` is the unique autoinc column for the table and can be used as an ID. `PRODUCTID` and `CUSTOMERID` both reference other tables.

`Customer` table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS 
(
  CUSTOMERID     NUMERIC(10,0) NOT NULL,
  WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE    VARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMERS PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMERID)
);
```

`Customers` table has records:

```
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (1, 'Reseller');
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (2, 'Reseller');
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (3, 'Reseller');
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (4, 'Installer');
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (5, 'Installer');
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (6, 'Installer');
insert into CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMERID, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE) values (7, 'Installer');
```

`Stockist` table has records:

```
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (1, 1, -100, 1);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (2, 1, -101, 2);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (3, 1, -102, 3);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (4, 1, -103, 4);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (5, 1, -104, 5);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (6, 1, -105, 6);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (7, 1, -106, 7);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (10, 2, -107, 3);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (13, 2, -108, 6);
insert into INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS (STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, CUSTOMERID) values (14, 2, -109, 7);
```

For the combined results:

```
select
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.STOCKISTID,
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.PRODUCTID,
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.DISPLAYORDER,
    CUSTOMERS.WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE
from
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS
left join
    CUSTOMERS on CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID = INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.CUSTOMERID
order by
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.PRODUCTID,
    CUSTOMERS.WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE,
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.DISPLAYORDER
```

Output:

```
STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE
7,  1, -106, Installer
6,  1, -105, Installer
5,  1, -104, Installer
4,  1, -103, Installer
3,  1, -102, Reseller
2,  1, -101, Reseller
1,  1, -100, Reseller
14, 2, -109, Installer
13, 2, -108, Installer
10, 2, -107, Reseller
```

I need to delete the 3rd and above record for each product/stockist type group ordered by display order, so would expect it to delete rows 5, 4, and 1.

I have tried heaps of different queries from here and the web generally, I can't find anything that will group and order for the delete and work on both MS SQL and Firebird 1.5.

SQL Fiddle to experiment with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7101de/1

So after deleting, the table should look like:

Output:

```
STOCKISTID, PRODUCTID, DISPLAYORDER, WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE
7,  1, -106, Installer
6,  1, -105, Installer
3,  1, -102, Reseller
2,  1, -101, Reseller
14, 2, -109, Installer
13, 2, -108, Installer
10, 2, -107, Reseller
```

The delete should be executed as one query, so I can pass it to the server.

*** Edit:

Maybe to simplify, if I can do a select command that returns the `STOCKISTID`'s to be deleted, I can then execute the delete commands seperately.

*** Edit 2:

As a test, I added the stockist type field to the INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS table, and can run this query:

```
SELECT INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.STOCKISTID
FROM   INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS IWS1
WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS  IWS2
WHERE IWS2.PRODUCTID = IWS1.PRODUCTID
AND IWS2.STOCKISTTYPE = IWS1.STOCKISTTYPE
AND IWS2.DISPLAYORDER <= IWS1.DISPLAYORDER) > 2
```

and return the correct fields (ie the ones that should be deleted). This was based on a question asked previously on SO.

As soon as I try and link in the CUSTOMER table as the query should be, it gives different results, less rows. Maybe someone might be able to help with that?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please show your expected output?

Comment: I need a delete command that would group the records by PRODUCTID and WEBSTOCKISTTYPE, then put then in DISPLAYORDER, and then delete any of the records in that group after the second ones. So from that output, it would just delete STOCKISTID's of 5, 4 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I have used ROW_NUMBER to eliminate your case (From what I understood from your question)

```
    ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCTID,WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE
                          ORDER BY (SELECT 1) )SNO, INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.*,
                         CUSTOMERS.WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE FROM
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS
    LEFT JOIN
      CUSTOMERS ON INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID
     )

     SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE SNO <3
```

Edit: From your comments:

```
    ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCTID,WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE
        ORDER BY (SELECT DISPLAYORDER) )SNO, INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.*,
        CUSTOMERS.WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE FROM
    INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS
    LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMERS ON INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID
    )
    SELECT STOCKISTID FROM CTE WHERE SNO>2
```

If it is a problem with CTE

```
    DELETE FROM INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS WHERE STOCKISTID IN ( 

    SELECT STOCKISTID FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY PRODUCTID,WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE
                ORDER BY (SELECT DISPLAYORDER) )SNO, INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.*,
                CUSTOMERS.WEBSTOCKISTSTOCKISTTYPE FROM
            INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS
            LEFT JOIN
            CUSTOMERS ON INVENTORYWEBSTOCKISTS.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID
            ) AS A WHERE SNO>2
            )
```

Comment: This is good, just replace `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` with `ORDER BY DISPLAYORDER)`.

Comment: @FelixPamittan Yup, I have undestood it wrongly first. From comments i made it clear

Comment: Sorry, firebird 1.5 doesn't have CTE. Plus I need to be able to do it as one query (all the queries I saw had he select and delete in one query so I didnt think to add that).

Comment: Then just remove cte and use sub query @Darren. Does Sub query work with  firebird 1.5??

Comment: I have added sub query in my ans @Darren

Comment: Sorry, that command on the fiddle didn't delete any rows and on firebird gives an error on the first select on the 3rd line. I know firebird does the nested selects, but I am not sure if you can nest them inside the nesting. Also I am not sure if partition is a firebird 1.5 command.

Comment: ... and no rownumber() function in firebird.

Comment: @Darren `row_number()` is added in Firebird 3 (currently in release candidate stage).

Comment: I abandoned the firebird requirement and implemented only for SQL Server, so the final SQL command without CTE does in fact work well.